# AWS signature version 4 signing key issue ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, authorization

Has to be done in ruby
my code is:

```
require "openssl"
require "time"
require "uri"
require "pathname"

def getSignatureKey (key, dateStamp, regionName, serviceName)
  digest= OpenSSL::Digest.new('sha256')
  kDate = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, ("AWS4" + key), dateStamp)
  puts("kdate:  #{kDate}")
  kRegion = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, kDate, regionName)
  puts("kRegion:  #{kRegion}")
  kService = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, kRegion, serviceName)
  puts("kService:  #{kService}")
  kSigning = OpenSSL::HMAC.hexdigest(digest, kService, "aws4_request")
  puts("kSigning:  #{kSigning}")
  kSigning
end

key = 'wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG+bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY'
dateStamp = '20120215'
regionName = 'us-east-1'
serviceName = 'iam'


puts("===========================================OUTPUT IS: ==============================================")
getSignatureKey(key,dateStamp,regionName,serviceName)
```

which produces the output:

**kdate**: 969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d
**kRegion**:a59e30f9d899c47b3dd68ea1c0ab3bb529e03a8f4ed2f54cb64af547330a22a0
**kService**:e33cbcda009243ed24c04af249a477d33b33c97ba7717327636afab2c6e6ef78
**kSigning**:9d8a8749deaee911a4ed0d04fb34af903f690d0423c146023bd282ba8ebf955b

however the output should be, according to aws documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-v4-examples.html):

**kdate**:  969fbb94feb542b71ede6f87fe4d5fa29c789342b0f407474670f0c2489e0a0d
**kRegion**:69daa0209cd9c5ff5c8ced464a696fd4252e981430b10e3d3fd8e2f197d7a70c
**kService**:f72cfd46f26bc4643f06a11eabb6c0ba18780c19a8da0c31ace671265e3c87fa
**kSigning**:f4780e2d9f65fa895f9c67b32ce1baf0b0d8a43505a000a1a9e090d414db404d

so the kdate matches but the others do not, I haven't miss-spelled "us-east-1" so I'm really not sure why they don't match. If anyone could offer advice I'd be very grateful.

Comment: ah fixed it, the new key for each stage needed to be in binary not hex

Comment: Hello 

can you explain me how to fix this error